# Asio .hpp not found in VSCode, but is included in path

Tags: c++, boost-asio, apple-m1

I'm trying to use asio in VSCode with C++. I keep getting the warning:

> fatal error: 'asio.hpp' file not found
> #include <asio.hpp>

Using the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/buffer.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/internet.hpp>

int main(){

    asio::error_code ec;

    //Create a 'context which is like a platform specific interface
    asio::io_context context;

    //Get the address of somewhere we wish to connect to
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("93.184.216.34", ec),80);



    return 0;
}
```

In the include path UI settings, I have the following paths listed which should take care of things:

```
${workspaceFolder}/**
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/asio/**
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/asio/1.24.0_1/include
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/**
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0/include/boost
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0/include
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include
```

(there are redundant paths here but I am trying everything at this point)

Finally, it should be able to find the file since the file is there:
`ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asio/1.24.0_1/include ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asio/1.24.0_1/include`
Gives:

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asio/1.24.0_1/include:
> asio        asio.hpp

I would expect it to just find those files. I have also installed boost using brew. It is available at the boost path included.

I am using Mac M1 with Monterey 12.5.1, and VSCode Version: 1.74.2.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) I'm sure it'll help you get it configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `includePath` element in the json file is for intelliSense and not your compiler. If you aren't using `CMake` you will have to go into `tasks.json`, there you can specify additional compiler flags.

You want to add a flag: `-Ipath/to/asio`.

Comment: I tried this, but it gives the same error. My tasks.json has in args: "-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/asio/1.24.0_1/include/"